# Editing sudoers.d to allow www-data run a specific file

Tags: permissions, sudo, git

I am running an Ubuntu server using Amazon AWS and I am trying to allow www-data to run a specific file that will push code to my git repository.

The file is under /var/ and I named it push.sh. I made a file under sudoers.d and added the following line using visudo:

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /var/push.sh
```

Whenever I run

```
sudo -u www-data sudo -l
```

I get the following response, "User www-data may run the following commands on
        (serverip):
    (root) NOPASSWD: /var/push.sh". However when I try to run this code

```
sudo -u www-data sudo sh /var/push.sh
```

I am being asked to enter a password for www-data.

Also when I make a php file to run the code using shell_exec

```
sh /var/push.sh
```

works fine, but

```
sudo sh /var/push.sh
```

does not. I would do it this way but the problem is I need to use sudo in order for the git to push properly.

I am probably missing something simple but I've been stuck on this for hours. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

P.S. let me know if i need to give more information

Comment: What are the permissions of `push.sh`

Comment: It's set at octal mode 755

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entry

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /var/push.sh
```

allows `www-data` to execute **exactly** the command `/var/push.sh` without a `sudo` password. It does not extend the ability to `sudo sh /var/push.sh` or even `sh /var/push.sh`

To work the way that you want, you must make `/var/push.sh` executable in its own right i.e.

- make sure it has the appropriate shebang at the top (presumable `#!/bin/sh` since you are trying to run it explicitly with `sh`)
- make it executable by at least `www-data`

Then invoke it directly as `sudo -u www-data /var/push.sh`

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Got it to execute the file, just need to figure out why my git commits but won't push, but that's a whole different issue.

Comment: Also whenever I add that sheband to the top I get this error. "-bash: /var/push.sh: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory"

Comment: @MarkJohnson that's a classic symptom of having edited the file in a Windows 
 (or possibly Mac) text editor - the `^M` is a representation of the carriage return line-ending

Comment: Thanks for the help, I used dos2unix to fix it and code runs fine. I was using Atom to edit the .sh file. I also now realize that this is what caused me hours of frustations ._.